# Sending a CSV attachment to an email address within the CSV

Tags: email, csv, batch-file

I have a bat file which runs an SQLCMD to query my SQL db and export some invoice data to a CSV (with date stamp). Then I have another bat file which splits the CSV's into multiple files (based on customer code which is in column A).

The next thing that I need to work out if possible is if the individual CSV files contain an email address - can a bat file be created to read the email address in let's say column B - then send the CSV file as an attachment to this email address?

I plan to run this on a daily schedule.

After the emails have gone out - I have another bat file to move the CSV's into an archive folder.

There will be a variable amount of CSVs on a daily basis - for example on one day there could be 1 CSV, and the next there could be 6 CSVs.

There is also the CSV file naming which will be variable - for example one of the CSV's could be called INV_C102727.csv and another could be INV_C105666.csv. The convention use is INV_csv.

I have done some research into this, I have been pointed in the direction of links like http://www.robvanderwoude.com/email.php or http://retired.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm but from what I can see - these solutions assume you know the email address you are sending to - rather than it being dynamic like in this instance.

As always - any help with this would be much appreciated.
This will be one of the last pieces of my puzzle!

Regards
Rick

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an executable to send the email.  It looks like [SwithMail](https://www.tbare.com/software/swithmail/) is popular and supports sending attachments specified with a wildcard.

Comment: hi Jeremy, i'm struggling to see how swithmail can do this... i must admit it does sound fairly difficult what i'm asking. so maybe if i put in the customer code (e.g.: C222000) and their email address into a separate file - would a bat file be able to look at the filenames of the CSV's in a directory and match up the customer code with the appropriate email address - then send it off?

Comment: The advantage of swithmail is that it can take a command line parameter with a wildcard to attach all matching files.  That's the hardest part of the problem you presented.  Maybe you could talk to a programmer about your requirements?  It sounds like there are a few different ways you could get the CSV files from the database.